# Reading from a text file using xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I want read a word from a text file and use it to verify a password. Of course I realise this is not in any way secure and would never be used in the real world, but it is an assignment for a college course that I have to do. 
Every time I click submit, I am brought to the page 'messing.html', regardless of whether the password is correct or not... Can somebody please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>

<form name="login" onSubmit="return validateForm();" action="messing.html" method="post">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var user_input = document.login.pword.value;


        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","books.txt",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        var y =xmlhttp.responseText;




        if (user_input == y){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your password");
            return false;
        }
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the value of `y`? Is it really the same as `user_input`? Does it have a new line at the end of it?

Comment: my problem is that it never seems to get as far as the if/else statement - regardless of what the user enters, (even if he/she leaves the password field blank), login is successful. For testing purposes, all that is in the text file is abcd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `onsubmit`. Because you don't prevent the default action of the form. Your form is sent to messing.html and that will be loaded.

You need to prevent the default action on the form when you want to use `xmlHTTPRequest`.

```
function validateForm(e) {
     ....
   e.preventDefault(); //<--- magic
```

}

> on a side note. Using synchronous xmlHTTPRequest is considered bad practice and not allowed in modern browsers, since it could hang the browser if no response is available or takes a long time to load. In this case switching to asynchronous is simple.

```
function validateForm(e) {
    var user_input = document.login.pword.value;


    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","books.txt",true); //changed to true

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if (this.status == 200 && this.readystate == 4)
     {
       var y =xmlhttp.responseText;
       if (user_input == y){
          location.href = "messing.html";

       }
       else {
          alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your password");
          return false;
       }
     }            
    }
    xmlhttp.send();
    e.preventDefault();
```

}